# Prefill data in contact form 7 from rest api (GET REQUEST)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, contact-form-7, wordpress-rest-api

My current setup with contact form is as whenever someone clicks the form, I capture the employee id (from URM).

I want to achieve this :

1. Since I already have the employee ID, I wanted to hit a GET Request on my backend server and get all the available details for that employee and pre-fill the form and ask only for the data that I don't have on the backend.

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: nothing productive as of now. just browsing different solutions and checking if anything would work.

Comment: I meant if you could let us know what you tried we could help you better.